# Style-Binding using Computed Properties and VueX

Tags: binding, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How would I bind styles using computed properties in VueJS while integrating with VueX.

The issue I am having is in regards to my style properties not updating after a change in my VueX Store.

Code Examples:

```js
//VueX Store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state : {
  div: [
   {
    offset: 0,
    width: 1,
    text : 'Hello World'
   },
   {
    offset: 0,
    width: 1,
    text : 'Hello World As Well'
   }
  ]
  }
});
```

```html
//My component
<template>
 <div v-bind:style="{ width: width, left: offset}">
  <p>{{text}}</p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'divBox',
  computed : {
   text : function() {
    return this.$store.state.div[this.Id].text;
   },
   width : function() {
    return this.$store.state.div[this.Id].width;
   },
   offset : function() {
    return this.$store.state.div[this.Id].offset;
   }
  },
  props : ['Id']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of how to use vuex to do what you are wanting. https://jsfiddle.net/n9jmu5v7/770/ I assume your problem is the fact that your store does not contain any mutations https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html.

```
mutations: {
  bgChange: state => state.bg='grey',
  colorChange: state => state.color='green'
}
```

Also, remember that just because your using vuex doesn't mean you need to put everything into it, it is fine to keep local data in a component. For example component style information sounds like something that doesn't need to be shared with anything else (Obviously you may have a reason for storing it in vuex that does make sense).

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! 

I had mutations set btw -> but for some reason they weren't working properly.

Comment: @NathanielDeshpande if this answers the question don't forget to accept it as the right answer. If you figured out a better answer be sure to post it.